# Use Checkbox-Group to update multiple records?

Tags: visual-workflow, inputcheckboxes, spring-20, screen-flow

I'm trying to figure out flows work with multi-select checkboxes. At this point I can only select 1 id from the list, despite the flow debug logs showing that I have selected 2. I'm aware of the documentation that says that in a Group-Checkbox that it would only capture the last id of the value that was selected.

I have been able to get the behavior that I want with a multi-select picklist but it is not as user friendly as the group checkbox option.

Essentially, I want to be able to lookup a collection of opps, have the user check the boxes for the ones they want to update, and then performa a loop on those selected opps and update them.

[image: Flow Diagram]
[image: Group-Checkbox example]
[image: Working Example of Displaying the Records]
[image: Flow Debug Log]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this [Dual ListBox Flow Screen Component.](https://unofficialsf.com/duallistbox/) Because this component expects a collection of strings for the values that get displayed, you may need to first extract the Names and ID's of your Opportunities using  a couple of instances of the Extract Strings from Collections action available [here](https://unofficialsf.com/list-actions-for-flow/).

Comment: Thanks, want to make sure I can do this without a managed package.